# Java: byte[] to List<Long>

Tags: java, arrays

I have a byte[] that I would like to represent as a List where the elements are the plain value of each individual byte, for example if I have

```
byte[] buf; //filled elsewhere
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buf)); //prints [97, 99, -100]
```

I want to end up with an object equivalent to

```
new ArrayList<Long>{97, 99, -100};
```

How can I make this object from my original buf?

Answer (score 2):

Java 8:

```
byte[] buf = { 97, 99, -100 };
List<Long> list = LongStream.range(0, buf.length).map(i -> buf[(int) i]).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list);
```

output:

```
[97, 99, -100]
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any utility that can cast an array of one object type to a different object type. You can either get a `List` of bytes by using:

```
List<Byte> bytes = Arrays.asList(buf);
```

Or make your own utility method similar to:

```
public static List<Long> bytesToListOfLongs(byte[] bytes) {
    List<Long> longs = new ArrayList<Long>();
    longs.ensureCapacity(bytes.length);

    for (byte b: bytes) {
        longs.add(new Long(b));
    }

    return longs;
}
```

And later use it like:

```
    byte[] buf; //filled elsewhere
    List<Long> longs = bytesToListOfLongs(buf);
```

Comment: Note that casting `b` in `bytesToListOfLongs` method to `long` as in `(long)b` might be necessary. It's a [widening primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) though, so I'm not sure about it and I can't test it at the moment.